# Building a custom filter for my tastypi resource

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I have this working code to filter out from a list that I testing using a normal GET request at a test url:

```
tag_list = request.GET.get('tag_list').split('&')
tags = Tag.objects.all()

all_species = Species.objects.all()
filtered_species = [all_species.filter(tags__description=c) for c in tag_list]
species = reduce(and_, filtered_species, all_species)
```

request will look like:

```
/?tag_list=winged fruit&latex present&foo&bar
```

How or where do I add that as a custom filter to my api resource?

Answer (score 1):

Hi again we have met on #tastypie.

That was interested question and will answer it here again might be useful for others.

First your url should be in form:

```
/?tag_list=winged%20fruit&tag_list=latex%20present&tag_list=foo&tag_list=bar
```

Then to access to your `tag_list` in request you have to use special method `getlist`:

```
request.GET.getlist('tag_list')
```

### Edit:

I would implement query this way but probably this solution could be improved:

```
tag_phrases = request.GET.getlist('tag_list')

# Create OR query based on `tag_phrases`
query = Q(tags__description=tag_phrases[0])
for index, tag_phrase in tag_phrases:
    if index == 0:
        continue
    query |= Q(tags__description=tag_phrase)

species = Species.objects.filter(query)
# Some of species might be duplicated
species = set(species)
```

Comment: Hi again :-) So this wont work with the django ORM methods? Ill have to do a custom filter?